# Using geojson in a C# class with in ASP.NET core and MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, geojson

I'm trying unsuccessfully to create a MongoDB **GeoJsonFeatureCollection** from JSON in ASP.NET core.

*(environment: MongoDB C# driver v2.10.2, ASP.NET core v3.1)*

```
// a C# class which contains my geoJson features and intend to store in MongoDB
public class Route
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public GeoJsonFeatureCollection<GeoJson2DCoordinates> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the ASP.NET core controller, I'd like to have incoming JSON auto-converted to the Route class:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<Route> Create(Route route)  // FAILS HERE WITH NO PARAMETERLESS CONSTRUCTOR ERROR!
{
    _routeService.Create(route);  // send it off to MongoDB
    ...
}
```

I understand that this fails because MongoDB's [GeoJsonFeatureCollection](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/GeoJsonObjectModel/GeoJsonFeatureCollection.cs) doesn't have a parameterless constructor, 
so the incoming JSON can't be automatically mapped to the C# **Route** class.
But I can't seem to find an obvious workaround to this situation.

Possibilities I've considered:

1. Skip trying to map to a C# class and just work with **BsonDocuments** for everything.
    It seems like querying becomes a bit more complex with this option, and I lose the power of C#.  Seems to be advocated [here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-c-sharp-and-mongodb--creating-documents).
2. Somehow add a custom serializer for **GeoJsonFeatureCollection**.  I have no idea how to do this, but there is a possibly relevant serializer provided in MongoDB:

   https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/GeoJsonObjectModel/Serializers/GeoJsonFeatureCollectionSerializer.cs
3. Use a **string** to hold the geoJson **Data** in my C# class and perform the conversions manually:

   `public string Data { get; set; }`

   instead of:

   `public GeoJsonFeatureCollection<GeoJson2DCoordinates> Data { get; set; }`

   and then manually convert the string to a GeoJsonGeometryCollection via:

   `var geoCollection = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<GeoJsonGeometryCollection<TCoordinates>>(json);`

   but this seems ugly, requiring an extra JSON serialization in my javascript code and manual conversions in every HTTP endpoint.

What to do?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510650/c-sharp-mongodb-complex-class-serialization