# Store object in document ( MongoDB & ASP.NET Core 6 )

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

I'm trying to store an object in the document. This is my entity:

```cs
public Guid Id { get; set; } 
public string CreatedBy { get; set; } 
public string CreatedByIp { get; set; } 
public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }  
public string LastUpdatedBy { get; set; } 
public string LastUpdatedByIp { get; set; } 
public DateTime? LastUpdatedAt { get; set; }
public object LastContext { get; set; }
```

**LastContext** object that contains multiple properties must be stored in the document, but this is what is stored in the document:

[image]

Also, because of the architecture, I should not use MongoDB attributes for entity properties.

Comment: Have you tried to convert :LastContext" to an Json object and store that in the MongoDB? I had a similar issue and converting it to Json object stored it the right way for me.

Comment: @SimpForJS Do you mean to use JsonConvert.SerializeObject?

Comment: Not really. I used JObject class if I remember correctly.

Comment: @SimpForJS I can not use this method due to architecture

Comment: This should work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510650/c-sharp-mongodb-complex-class-serialization

Comment: Try `dynamic` keyword over `object` and see if there is a change and an upvote for the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can map your class to another class with same properties with JObject or JToken type , which can be stored in Mongo